# ffmpeg video splitting less then 10 sec gives black clip - ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04

I am using FFmpeg version 4.3-2~18.04.york0 on AWS EC2 server for video splitting, while I split video less then 11 seconds the output.mp4 gives a blank video. I have tried the same thing with my local MAC and Ubuntu 19 but it works fine.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:01:10 -to 00:01:15 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is use the duration flag instead of the end position flag in your command:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:01:10 -t 10 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4`

`-t 10` cuts 10 seconds from the starting position that `-ss` has specified.

If that still doesn't work, it would be helpful if you could clarify your question a bit:

- Are you using the same version of ffmpeg on the Mac and Ubuntu systems where it works fine?
- Are you using the same configuration (visible with `ffmpeg --help`) on all systems?
- Also, what's confusing to me is your question as a whole: You write that you have issues with videos of less than 11 seconds, but what you're trying to do in the command is cut 5 seconds of a video that seems to be at least 1min10s long (based on the starting position of `00:01:10`).

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens because the video segment you want to extract doesn't contain any [I-frame (key frame)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types#Intra-coded_(I)_frames/slices_(key_frames)). A video typically has one key frame every 10 seconds, so it's likely that your video segment doesn't have any because its duration is only 5 seconds.

There is [some caveat](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Seekingwhiledoingacodeccopy) on using video codec copy (`-c:v copy`). In your case  it's impossible to do a codec copy because your video segment doesn't have any key frame, hence a blank video.

To trim a video segment that has no key frame, you need to reencode it, i.e. by using other video codec option than `copy`, such as `-c:v x264`. To preserve the quality, you can set [crf to 17 or 18](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#a1.ChooseaCRFvalue):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:01:10 -to 00:01:15 -c:v x264 -crf 17 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Reencoding is always much slower than codec copy, but because the duration is only 5 seconds, it should take less than a minute to reencode it (depends on the CPU).

I'm not sure why your original command was working on your local computer. It might be due to a different version of ffmpeg or a different video source (e.g. `input.mp4` in your local happens to have a key frame in the timestamp range).